# Why Ajax success not called when JSON passed through Django?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I have an Ajax request that sends JSON data to a Django view, where a success message is then returned and displayed to the user.

The problem I am facing is Ajax success is not being called. I get an alert from the error part of the Ajax request with the HTTP status code 200 ("Received JSON successfully") but its not appended to the results div.

My understanding is that, I am possibly not returning the data correctly in the Django function to be used as HTML, hence why it is calling Ajax error.

**jQuery (Ajax):**

```
json_query = JSON.stringify(form_data);

$.ajax({
    url: "/stix_json/",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html",
    contentType: "application/json",

    data: { 
        client_response: json_query,
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
    },

    success: function(result){
        $('#results').html(result);
    },

    error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
        alert(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

**Django Views.py**

The url /stix_json/ calls the function in views.py process_json

```
def process_json(request):
    if request.POST.has_key('client_response'):

        x = request.POST['client_response']
        # Do something with JSON here

        success = "Received JSON successfully"
        return HttpResponse(success)

    else:
        return render(request, "stix_form.html")
```

I would appreciate if someone was able to explain why this issue occurs.

Answer (score 0):

In js
Change this `dataType: "html",`  to `dataType: "json",`

```
success: function(result){
    $('#results').html(result['status']);
},
```

and in views.py

```
import json
data = {'status':'Received JSON successfully'}
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type="application/json")
```

Comment: I already had it returning JSON originally, I wanted to try and return HTML/Text instead as I am going to process the JSON later on.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not returning HTML (not JSON..) but rather Text, You should change your `dataType` from `"html"` to `"text"`.

Comment: I think I had it right, it looks like the server wasn't updating my HTML file so it was still trying to return JSON. Issue is now for some reason the CSRF token is "invalid"